# Hive programming and queries

Tags: hive

Why is there is no Mapreduce Program gets launched when we run simply select * query in hive

```
select * from emp;
select * from emp limit 10;
select * from from limit 2;
```

For the above  hive queries there is no mapreduce program gets launched.

```
select id from emp;
select id,name from emp;
select * from emp where id>100;
```

For the above 3 hive queries map reduce program gets lauched.

Why is it? Could somebody explain this

Answer (score 2):

Whenever you run a normal 'select *', a fetch task is created rather than a mapreduce task which just dumps the data as it is without doing anything on it. This is equivalent to a:

```
hadoop fs -cat $file_name
```

So in case of your first 3 queries, a fetch task is invoked which is just doing a cat and displaying the data.

Whereas for the other queries, a map job is invoked which filters the complete row according to your condition (for example, select id from all the columns) and gives you the output

Answer (score 0):

You can use explain the sql in the hive client.

`explain select * from tablename;
The execution plan:
STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-0
    Fetch Operator
      limit: 10
      Processor Tree:
        TableScan
          alias: tablename`


`explain select dt from tablename;
STAGE PLANS:
  Stage: Stage-1
    Map Reduce
      Alias -> Map Operator Tree:
        src_f_log_user_leave 
          TableScan
            alias: tablename`

The difference of above two sql is first is fetch operator, another is Map Operator tree.